# Ajax - trying to replace instead of append

Tags: jquery, ajaxform

I know nothing about ajax. I'm using flask to run a web app with python. This is regarding the response after submitting a form. All is working fine, except every time I press submit the latest response is appended under the last (until you refresh the page). I have narrowed it down to only one possible section of the config based on the output.
This is the section I'm confused by:

```
    response =response.result;
                     $.each(response,function(key,val){
                     console.log(val);
                        html+="<p>"+val+"<p>"
    
                    });
                    html +="<br>";
                    $(".show-data").append(html);
                });
```

I noticed 'append(html)' which lead me to search some ajax functions.
I've tried:
'$(".show-data").**replaceWith**(html);'
which I've seen work elsewhere but not here.

Does anyone with a good understanding of Ajax have any ideas what to do here?
Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change your  `$(".show-data").append(html);` to  `$(".show-data").html(html);`

`html()` works more or less like innerHTML from standard javascript.

Comment: Perfect man, thank you. That was driving me insane